# Formatting cell based on previus cell

Tags: excel

[enter image description here]
[image: 1]
Cell values in Excel like column A

If the number in cell A above is equal or higher only  for max 2, then put 1 in cell B

If the number in cell A above is lower, do nothing

If the number in cell A above is higher that 2, do nothing

Anyone that can help me? Thanks :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to S.O. please note that this is not a free code writing service. Can you let us know what you tried, exactly, and what the problem you encountered is? We'll then be happy to help you resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 `IF` statements, the first to check if the cell above is higher or lower than the current cell and the second one to perform the check for the difference between them.  I believe this formula will work for you

`=IF(A2>=A1,IF(A2-A1<=2,1,""),"")`

Comment: Yes, this formula will work for me, thank you

I have 4000 cell (A1 to A4000), how I will enter this formula to B2 to B4000 cell ?

Comment: @Mike As I said in my post, you put the formula into cell B2 and copy down. That applies to Glenn G's, formula as well as to the formula I suggested.

Comment: @teylyn and Glenn G Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not "formatting". It needs a formula that returns the number into the cell.

There are different ways to calculate that. You can do a comparison with "greater than" and "less than", but a much simpler way is subtracting the number from the cell above from the current row. If the remainder is 2 or less, then return a 1, if it is greater than 2 return a blank.

Start in cell B2 with

```
=IF(A2-A1<=2,1,"")
```

Copy down.

If the numbers are not consecutively increasing in column A, you also need to include a condition to check that the current row value is bigger or equal to the previous row's value.

```
=IF(AND(A2>=A1,A2-A1<=2),1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: This gives false positives if A2 < A1.

Comment: Yes, this gives false positives if A2 < A1 thanks

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't see that there were smaller values in column a further down. I added that scenario to my answer.